Rotate view for cartopy
I am creating the following map.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

# Create a plot using the PlateCarree projection
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6), subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})

# Set the extent for the Amazon region in regular latitude/longitude coordinates
ax.set_extent([-74, -32, -5, 15], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Add features to the map
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')

# Add gridlines with labels
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, linestyle='--', color='gray')
gl.top_labels = False  # Disable top labels
gl.right_labels = False  # Disable right-side labels
gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 10, 'color': 'black'}
gl.ylabel_style = {'size': 10, 'color': 'black'}

# Display the map
plt.show()


but I want to rotate the view to alight the x axis with the coast orientation by giving the coordinates of this box.


Well, I could kind of find a solution for that, but wanted to understand some of the commands.
# Define projection parameters
projection_center = (280, 25.5)  # (longitude, latitude)
azimuth = 165  # azimuth of the oblique equator in degrees

# Create an Oblique Mercator projection
oblique_mercator = ccrs.ObliqueMercator(central_longitude=projection_center[0],
                                         central_latitude=projection_center[1],
                                         azimuth=azimuth)
# Create a new figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), subplot_kw={'projection': oblique_mercator})

# Set the extent for the Amazon region in regular latitude/longitude coordinates
_,ymin = oblique_mercator.transform_point(-60, 0, ccrs.PlateCarree())
_,ymax = oblique_mercator.transform_point(-40, 5, ccrs.PlateCarree())

xmin,_ = oblique_mercator.transform_point(-75, 5, ccrs.PlateCarree())
xmax,_ = oblique_mercator.transform_point(-40, -10, ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.set_extent([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax], crs=oblique_mercator)

# Add features to the map
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')

ax.gridlines()
ax.invert_yaxis() # for some reason
ax.invert_xaxis() # for some reason

# Add gridlines with labels
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, linestyle='--', color='gray')
gl.top_labels = False  # Disable top labels
gl.right_labels = False  # Disable right-side labels
gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 10, 'color': 'black'}
gl.ylabel_style = {'size': 10, 'color': 'black'}



I basically played with projection_center and azimuth, but don't understand how to obtain them based on how much I want to rotate the map. Anyone can explain that?
I'm also not sure why I had to invert x and y axis.
